# Return every 200:th rows, plus last row

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to return every 200:th row and also the last row. If less than 200 rows, just return the last one.

If my table has e.g. 333 rows, return row 200 and row 333.

I try to used `mod(SQN,200)='0'`, but the No.333 record will be missing.

Thank your help.

Comment: are you using oracle or mysql -- there is a big difference.

Comment: sorry i am using Oracle

Comment: Why the number zero as a string literal? I'd do mod(SQN,200)=0

Comment: I do mod(SQN,200)=0. it's still missing no.333 record.

Comment: row_number is what you're looking for.

Comment: @DavidAldridge how does row_number help -- he already has SQN

Comment: @Hogan what is an sqn in Oracle?

Comment: @DavidAldridge sqn is nothing in oracle -- it is in the question.  He represents SQN as an integer field he can mod by 200 to get every 200th row.

Comment: @Hogan, then that would be "every row for which SQN is an integer multiple of 200, and the row having the maximum value of SQN".

Comment: Hi I post my code for your reference. The question is I try to addfrom   (select *,
               max(sqn) over () max_sqn
        from   table)  but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ryder Use the row_number() method.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Could you show me how to use the number() I try but seems wrong way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function in oracle to know the rowid `rownum`. Specially if SQN isnt consecutive.

I create a cte to add the `newID`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69dce6/1)**

```
WITH maxN as (
    Select count(*) as N 
    from Employee
),
rowmod as (
    SELECT "Name", "id", rownum as newID
    FROM Employee 
)
SELECT *
FROM rowmod, maxN
WHERE mod(newID, 21) = 0
   or newID = N
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|     Name | id | NEWID |   N |
|----------|----|-------|-----|
|  Jocelyn | 89 |    21 | 100 |
|    Quail |  8 |    42 | 100 |
| Theodore | 28 |    63 | 100 |
|  Shelley | 90 |    84 | 100 |
|    Malik | 49 |   100 | 100 |
```

Comment: If you use the analytic function "count(*) over ()" then you can avoid the need for the subquery factoring clause.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Sound good, but wouldn't the `count() over` execute for each row? I mean would be that better in performance?

Comment: `WHERE mod(rownum, 200) = 0` No can do. `rownum` only increments when a row is included in the result. So the first row, `rownum` starts as one, fails `mod(rownum, 200) = 0`, next row, rownum is still one. This is also why `rownum between 10 and 20` fails for paging.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Thanks, I tought was a bug in the fiddle and invent the workaround on the second sample. I will delete first one.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza No, it's treated in an efficient manner. It's obviously not cost-free, and you can't place a predicate directly on it (you'd push the query into a subquery and select from it).

Answer (score 0):

If you want "every row for which SQN is an integer multiple of 200, and the row having the maximum value of SQN", then:

```
select *
from   (select *,
               max(sqn) over () max_sqn
        from   table)
where  mod(sqn,200) = 0
   or  sqn          = max_sqn
```

If SQN was not a sequential integer, but you wanted every 200th row etc when order by sqn, then:

```
select *
from   (select *,
               row_number() over (order by sqn) rownumber,
               count(*) over () row_count
        from   table)
where  mod(rownumber,200) = 0
   or  rownumber          = row_count
```

Comment: This looks a lot like my answer from 10 mins ago.

Comment: Except that it is valid SQL.

Comment: I doubt it... if the table was named table you would need to quote the name.

Comment: I doubt the table is really called table. What I mean is that the max needs to be an analytic function with a window clause.

Comment: I know that is what you meant but you are wrong.  Try it.  MAX does not need to be window or group by last I checked.

Comment: Or you could use `rownum` function

Comment: I post my code but I think SQN couldn't be in 'from' because SQN in Select as ?Maybe i got wrong. ?

Comment: @Hogan, you don't need `group by` or analytic as long as every column is an aggregate function. As soon as you add another column you need to group or turn max into an analytic function. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/6910 (For Oracle which this question is tagged, SQL Server and others. This statement may not be true for mysql.)

Comment: Whether SQN is a column name, or the result of a call to a function, you can still use it in row_number or the analytical function's window clause. Where in my code you see "from table", replace table with your query inside ()'s

Comment: @Shannon for Postgresql you could get away with group by on only the primary key of the table, rather logically, instead of having to include all the columns in the select clause, so it's different (and better) than Oracle in that respect.

Comment: @DavidAldridge  update my code could you help point me where is wrong ?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance - your fiddle is broken -- but you might be correct, I only tested on DB2.

Comment: @Ryder have a look at how I use it in the second query of my answer.

Comment: @Hogan, define broken. Returns an error? That was the point, that form of max does not work in Oracle. (Weird error though.)

Comment: @ShannonSeverance - ok I guess it is just a strange error message.  of course when I try to have the syntax you show above that also does not work.

Comment: I try to use your second answer but it seems into a infinity loop.

Comment: How do you mean, a loop? Are you getting an error message? What's the symptom?

Answer (score -1):

This is a very hard problem -- you need to use a logical OR.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, MAX(SQN) as SQNmax
  FROM TABLE
)
WHERE MOD(SQN,200) = 0 OR SQN = SQNmax
```

If the max(sqn) does not work you can do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
JOIN (SELECT MAX(SQN) as SQNmax FROM TABLE) sub
WHERE MOD(SQN,200) = 0 OR SQN = sub.SQNmax
```

Comment: I just post my code. But SQN could be in FROM ? because my SQN is in Select as SQN. So in my case , does it works ?

Comment: my SQN  need to replace ?  it showed  'SQL command not properly ended' error

Comment: @Ryder did you include all `)` and a `;`?

Comment: is there any missing ?

Comment: @Ryder you have to put the join after all the items in the from list -- you can't stick it in a random place.  Put it at the line directly before the where no `,` before or after

Comment: Now it said missing key word at where. would you help to check thank you very much.

Comment: @Ryder - I'm not interested in debugging your that code has my line commented out.